# Using linear gradient breaks the CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have some images that I am trying to make a slideshow out of. I am using CSS to give a fade in-out effect. Here is an example of some code that DOES work and transitions correctly:

```
.hero {
  background-image: url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg');
  animation: changeBackground 30s infinite;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

/* Calculate each background % based on how many photos will be shown and for how long*/
/* We need both urls listed in each group to prevent the screen from flashing between background imgs */
@keyframes changeBackground {
  0%,
  6%,
  12% {
    background-image: url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/2.jpg');
  }
  24%,
  30%,
  36% {
    background-image: url('/slideshow_images/2.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/3.jpg');
  }
  48%,
  54%,
  60% {
    background-image: url('/slideshow_images/3.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/4.jpg');
  }
  72%,
  78%,
  84% {
    background-image: url('/slideshow_images/4.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg');
  }
}
```

**However**, when I add a `linear-gradient` to each photo. The smooth transition stops. Now the background changes without any animation whatsoever. It simply changes. Here is an example of the code I  tried:

```
.hero {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg');
    animation: changeBackground 15s infinite;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes changeBackground {
    0%,
    6%,
    12% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/2.jpg');
    }
    24%,
    30%,
    36% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('/slideshow_images/2.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/3.jpg');
    }
    48%,
    54%,
    60% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('/slideshow_images/3.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/4.jpg');
    }
    72%,
    78%,
    84% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('/slideshow_images/4.jpg'), url('/slideshow_images/1.jpg');
    }
}
```

How can I keep the animation like I had in the first snippet, but add a linear-gradient to the images? BTW, the reason I have two image URL's in each group is because this fixed the problem I had where the screen would flash when the background-image changed

Comment: In general, transitions just work for the same properties. e.g., the margin in px doesn't work transitioning to margin auto. In your case, just keep the linear gradient outside the property (as I see, all gradients are the same values). I'd suggest you use `.hero::after` to apply that gradient

Comment: Can you explain a little more please? Not sure I follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Animations

Animations just work when you define same kind of values.
For example this won't work bacause the margin changes from 10px to auto:

```css
/* This will blink */
@keyframes animationTest {
  0%{margin:10px}
  100%{margin:auto}
}
```

To make it work, the transition should calculate being equivalent, for example px to px:

```css
@keyframes animationTest {
  0%{margin:10px}
  100%{margin:20px}
}
```

### Adding a second background

Said so, mixing gradients with background images will always blink.
Your solution is to split the values. This is how to apply a second background property without affecting the previous animation

```css
/* add to .hero relative position */
.hero {
  position: relative;
}

/* Define your second background separately. 
You can also apply an animation */
.hero::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I want to have more than 2 backgrounds? How many CSS classes would I need?

Comment: I don't see how the first half of your answer is relevant. OP doesn't have px to auto property conversions to worry about here. They know how animations work; they use them successfully in their first code snippet.

Comment: @TylerH It is the concept problem generating the blink, it seems relevant for me to explain to somebody who is learning. About your question @mcool, if you need more backgrounds, the next pseudo selector to use would be `:before`, keeping that logic. If you need something more complex than CSS Animations can offer, I'd suggest opting for a JavaScript library.